# C# compilation failure expression is too long or complex to compile

Tags: c#, msbuild, csc

This is a C# project with .NET 4.6.1 and we were building this by invoking MSBuild.exe that comes with .NET 4.6.1. The code used to be compiled successfully using C# compiler csc.exe which has version below --

```
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>csc.exe /version
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.1055.0
for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Due to certain unavoidable infrastructure policies we have to now build this project in a different build machine. The new build machine uses an older version of csc.exe compiler seen below --

```
E:\....\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn>csc.exe /version
2.9.0.63208 (958f2354)
```

However, a couple of cs (C#) files are failing compilation giving the follow error with the older version of the csc.exe compiler --

```
 SysimageServiceSerializer.cs(13475,151): error CS8078: An expression is too long or complex to compile
```

I understand the reason of this error which is caused because of the compiler running out of space and the solution would be to simplify the code. However, these would cause lot of code changes. I am thinking if there is any way to resolve this without doing code changes.

I saw this link https://www.grapecity.com/en/forums/spread-archive/error-an-expression-is-too and tried the option given there to add below tag in the csproj file

```
<UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>false</UseHostCompilerIfAvailable>
```

Also tried invoking MSBuild with the couple of additional arguments  /t:rebuild and /maxcpucount:20. But still no luck.

Any idea how to resolve this without code changes, it was getting compiled earlier as mentioned above but failing once we are using older version of csc.exe

Comment: Did you try `editbin`, as suggested in your link?

Comment: No i didnt try that yet. Will try this out

Comment: FWIW, `4.6.1` and `4.7.2` are not MSBuild version, but those of the .NET Framework. To get MSBuild's version run `<fullpath>\msbuild.exe /version`. Apart from that, MSBuild has propbably very little todo with this issue, but the C# compiler itself. Inspect the detailed (`msbuild.exe /v:d`) output of your builds, notice the full path to `csc.exe` and query their versions (`<fullpath>\csc.exe /version`). The `UseHostCompilerIfAvailable` if available only does something when building inside Visual Studio.

Comment: As for your case, this error happens - more often then otherwise - when attempting to compile overly complex, generated, serializer files. Search the internet for "CS8078 serializer" and see if anybody has found a practical solution that you could use as well to reduce the complexity of the generated file.

Comment: Hi Christian, you are very right, its nothing to do with MSBuild.exe  but with the version of the csc.exe compiler being used. Have edited my question accordingly. Verified that now we are using older version of csc.exe and hence compilation is failing. Thinking how to resolve this without either (a) switching back to newer version of csc.exe or (b) making code changes. Actually I am getting more than 300 instances of this  CS8078 error code and hence doing code changes is my last resort. Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way, I tried running editbin.exe as suggested but that didnt work also. So I think the options available now are to ask our infra team to put new version of csc.exe  in the build machine or modify our code to make it compile with roslyn csc.exe -:)